WebClientRequestException: Pending acquire queue has reached its maximum size of XX
for ilustration purposes I have this code:
// remote Echo server
@GetMapping("echo")
public Mono<String> echo(){
    return Mono.just("echo");
                
}

// client 1 conneciton
ConnectionProvider provider =
                ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
                                  .maxConnections(50)
                                  .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))           
                                  .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(60))           
                                  .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)) 
                                  .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(120))    
                                  .build();


HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider);

WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
                          .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/echo")
                          .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                          .build();

// run
Flux.range(1, 5000)
    .flatMap(i -> client.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class))    
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .subscribe();    

I get easily the next error:

WebClientRequestException: Pending acquire queue has reached its maximum size of 32

I know it has been asked before how to solve this error like in here Facing issue "WebClientRequestException: Pending acquire queue has reached its maximum size of 1000" with spring reactive webClient. The solutions involve modifying certain parameters of the pool, delay elements, etc but in my opinion this is not resilient because my whole configuration of the pool depend on predictions about the response times of the Echo Server. If any day the Echo server is really slow, I will get the error specified easily and this is not resilient.
My point is that making an http call non blocking is causing the Thread that makes the request to go back to emit another item of the Flux without waiting for the previous Http connnections to end.
How to be resilient in this kind of situation without relying on time predictions?

Are you sure about this piece of code, because it disables the connection pooling: HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.newConnection())?

Yes, you are right. I edited the code in order to correct it. But my point is supposing we have a configured http pool, how to get rid of this kind of predictions and be resilient in case the Echo server is really slow at any time?
